# Create C++ Shared Library from Simulink in Linux

Tags: c++, matlab, shared-libraries, simulink

I need to generate a shared library (.so) file from a Simulink model, with inputs and outputs, and run this model step by step in another C++ project.

I am aware that the MATLAB Code Generator is able to generate executables and DLLs. Nonetheless, I could not find how to generate Linux C++ shared libraries. I would appreciate if someone could explain how to generate these libraries, with a minimal working example on how to import and use them in C++.

**EDIT**

I managed to create a shared library and a sample C++ project in Qt Creator. Somehow I was missing the target file **ert_shrlib.tlc**. This is the what I did:

***Configure the Simulink Model***

- Create a simple continuous Simulink model with two inputs, and two outputs, named: **simul_main.slx**.
- In "Configuration Parameters"->"Code Generation", select the target **ert_shrlib.tlc** for the Embedded Coder.
- In "Configuration Parameters"->"Code Generation"->"Interface", set:

  - Code replacement library: C99 (ISO)
  - Support: floating-point numbers, and continuous time.
- In "Configuration Parameters"->"Code Generation"->"Interface"->"Configure Model Functions", set:

  - Initialize function name: **init_simul**
  - Step function name: **step_simul**

***Build the Shared Library***

- Build the model to generate code.

***Configure the MWE Qt Project***

- test.pro

  ```
  TEMPLATE = app
  CONFIG += console
  CONFIG -= qt

  LIBS += -L<path_to_lib> -lsimul_main  
  INCLUDEPATH += <path_to_sources>
  INCLUDEPATH += <path_to_matlab>/simulink/include/  

  SOURCES += main.cpp
  ```
- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <cstdio>

  extern "C"
  {
  #include "simul_main.h"
  #include "simul_main_private.h"
  }

  int_T main()
  {
      /* Initialize the model */
      init_simul();

      real_T input1 = 1, input2 = 1;
      real_T time;
      real_T output1, output2;
      real_T tfinal = 10;

      while ((rtmGetErrorStatus(simul_main_M) == (NULL)) && !rtmGetStopRequested(simul_main_M))
      {
          /* Step the model for base rate */
          step_simul(input1, input2, &output1, &output2);

          /* Get simulation time */
          time = rtmGetT(simul_main_M);

          /* Display simulation output */
          std::printf("%5.2f : [%5.2f, %5.2f]\n", time, output1, output2);

          /* Request simulation to stop */
          if (time >= tfinal)
              rtmSetStopRequested(simul_main_M, true);
      }

      /* Terminate the model */
      simul_main_terminate();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Note that the `step_simul` function signature may be configured in the "Configure Model Functions" dialogue.

Comment: You need to have the [Embedded Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/features.html).  There are various examples within that product's documentation, which although not linux specific, should be pretty easy to get to work in linux.